# Passing cookie from different domain example.co.uk to example.com

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, cross-domain, cookie-httponly

I am trying to access cookie on **example.com** API endpoint from **example.co.uk** site but the cookie is not being passed because of cross domain.

I am using axios to make request call and passing withCredentials: true

Since the cookie is httponly cookie, its not accessible from JavaScript.

Let me know if there any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: What is the `SameSite` policy of the cookie? `Secure`?

Comment: Its not specified for this cookie

Comment: Then you *could* specify it to be `None` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) but that potentially opens you up to attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I cannot set this to None since this cookie is getting used for Auth purpose.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. The cookie does exactly what it is supposed to do, it prevents you from executing a (potentially malicious) request to example.com from an unrelated domain. You should change your domain structure to not serve front and backend from unrelated domains.